# Second DP Monitor Not recognized on Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.1, With 3090 RTX

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS from Ubuntu 20.04, where I had both monitors working just fine.

After upgrade to Ubuntu22.04.1, my second monitor (both connected via DP cables) is not recognized, even after changing driver versions and following advice from similar questions on the web.

My current driver is nvidia-driver-515.

Does anyone have an idea how to get the second monitor to display?

Comment: Wayland or Xorg?

Comment: You are using Ubuntu Core. Core is the only version of Ubuntu to use a single digit version number. If this is not what you are using please EDIT the question and correct it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, will update the question.

Comment: @Esther XDG_SESSION_TYPE is showing 'x11'

Comment: I should note, when the first monitor is disconnected, the second one starts working. Both work normally under Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be a few similar issues on the Nvidia forums, including a bug report here shows that the driver is loaded nearly 21 minutes after the machine boots - are you seeing this?
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/only-one-monitor-works-with-recommended-driver/219560

I had the same issue and the problem went away when I switched to `nvidia-driver-470`, and there was no change in performance.

You can see which monitors are detected with `xrandr | grep \ connected` or `xrandr --listmonitors`.

I haven't got around to testing the 520 driver yet, which is available here: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/193764/en-us/

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I downgraded to 470, but also needed to remove some old xorg.conf files, and after a reboot the second monitor works!